# Modifying postgresql.conf through shell?

Tags: postgresql, shell

I want to modify a postgresql.conf parameter through the shell. From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/config-setting.html) I can see that I can use the `postgres` command with the `-c` flag.

However, on my attempt, for example,

```
postgres -c autovacuum=off
```

`postgres` returns:

> Execution of PostgreSQL by a user with administrative permissions is not permitted.
>
> The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent possible system security compromises. See the documentation for more information on how to properly start the server.

How can I overcome this or what is the correct procedure? Also, I don't really mind for security compromises.

Comment: To be clear, `postgres -c foo=bar` (when it works) doesn't update postgresql.conf -- instead, it *starts the postgres server*, with `foo` overridden to have the value `bar` only that one time the server is started (but leaving `foo` at its normal value in the ongoing configuration for future invocations).

Comment: BTW, it's not clear what "don't really mind for" means. Do you mean to say you don't mind compromises -- that is, you find compromises acceptable?

Comment: If you want to modify the config file, just append to it with `echo`, or use `sed` to rewrite it. Or enable an `include_file` or `include_directory` and write new parameters there. Or use `ALTER SYSTEM SET`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am doing something personal, locally and temporarily so I don't need this extra protection which the quoted message is referring to turned on. I thought this was quite clear. Also thanks for the information.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks, your solutions are very neat. That tackles what I had in mind while writing this question and much more.

Comment: @audlift-bit, my point was that in American English, the phrase "don't really mind for" is unidiomatic. I *did* provide suggested, alternate wording in my comment (to say that "I'm willing to compromise security", for instance, is entirely unambiguous). I'm not arguing the content -- whether you should or should not be willing to compromise security -- rather, I'm arguing the language used to convey it. :)

Comment: Anyhow -- `-c autovacuum=off` may be possible to provide at startup time, but first we'd need to know *how* your server is being started up -- which means knowing your OS distro/version/release. If you're using systemd one could provide an overlay to the service file; if it's an OS that uses `/etc/rc.d`-style init scripts the argument could be added there; and of course the approaches Craig suggested are available.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was starting to think it was a poke at my decision to be lax with security (it happens quite often here!) - sure, I can see why it would be a little bit off (British here) so I would like to apologise. I am well-covered with what Craig has offered but for the sake of the discussion, I am using Windows.

Comment: Hmm. If you're willing to continue that discussion -- Cygwin? Windows Services for Unix? Windows Subsystem for Linux? Is the PostgreSQL package installed a native-win32 one (ie. a MSI install package), or one built for one of the aforementioned? (I'm a bit curious inasmuch as I'm realizing that I *don't know* how PostgreSQL startup is typically controlled on Windows -- but to direct research on the subject appropriately that would require knowing the details of that installation).

Comment: Sure, I am building PostgreSQL with MinGW 64 on Windows. I don't know the details about PostgreSQL startup so much but I am setting some environment variables and starting my cluster though pg_ctl. I am on Windows because I am a bit limited with resources. Do you think I am disadvantaged in some way by using this OS and MinGW?

Answer (score 1):

Given the differences on the underlying OS, I usually prefer to do this via PostgreSQL itself, which comes handy when you're dealing with a managed service that do not give you filesystem access, like so:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -d database_name -c "alter system set postgresql_parameter = 'new_value';"
```

As an example when I have to install TimeScaleDB extension, I can do:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -d database_name -c "alter system set shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb';"
sudo service postgresql restart
sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -d database_name -c "create extension if not exists timescaledb;"
```